# Virtualbox Windows 10 Guest installation is freezing up in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, windows, virtualbox

I've installed VirtualBox using the Software Centre and I'm running a system on Ubuntu 14.04 with 8gb RAM, 64-bit dual core processor.

I want to run Windows 10, I've tried both 64 and 32 bit versions, in virtualbox. However, every time I start up windows 10 it gets to the point where the dots go round in a circle, then it freezes up and crashes back to the virtualbox manager. The only information it gives me is that the virtual machine was aborted.

I've changed the settings around a lot and nothing is working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Oh, and I've run Windows 10 technical preview on this machine before, a while ago

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although this question is quite close to being off-topic here ...

Install VirtualBox 5.0 which has improved Windows 10 support.

Remove the old VirtualBox version :

```
sudo apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"
```

Update the software repositories :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Download and register the ORACLE public key:

```
wget -q -O - https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the ORACLE VirtualBox repository :

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-vbox.list
```

Update the software repositories again :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install ORACLE VirtualBox 5.0 :

```
sudo apt-get install dkms virtualbox-5.0
```

Download the [Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and install them by opening the Preferences.

To avoid any problems - it is recommended to restart the Ubuntu system before using VirtualBox.

**Note for other users reading this answer, in case they use another Ubuntu edition as 14.04 :**

You have to replace `trusty` with the Ubuntu edition you are using when adding the repository !

As of Ubuntu 16.04 the ORACLE public key to download and register has  changed :

`oracle_vbox.asc` has to be replaced with `oracle_vbox_2016.asc` !