# Windows 10 Hangs in VirtualBox in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I am trying to install Windows 10 (64 bit) OS in Virtualbox in Ubuntu 16.04. When I run the setup from virtual box to install Windows 10, it hangs at the Windows logo screen and never proceeds further and shows NO error messages. Check the screenshot[image: Windows hang in Virtualbox during isntallation]

What's the problem here?

Comment: What is the VB version?

Comment: And did you enable graphics acceleration in VM settings?

Comment: Could you provide VirtualBox settings and your hardware information??

Answer (score 6):

I just fixed the same issue by installing the latest version of virtualbox. So Windows 10 doesn't hang on virtualbox 5.1.26. The answer for this [Virtualbox Windows 10 Guest installation is freezing up in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715988/virtualbox-windows-10-guest-installation-is-freezing-up-in-14-04) question contains stepwise instruction.

Comment: Yes, bro! Thanks!) It booted with 5.1 version, 5.0 can't.